# Styling wordpress heading

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My css classes are not affecting the `h1` containing the wp `single_post_title()`

```
    <div class="intro-text child">
      <!--<h1 class="herotext sr-hero">Kompletní<br>realizace staveb.</h1>-->
      <?php
      if ( is_front_page() ) {
          echo '
              <img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/samsonsvg2_animated.svg" class="samsonlogo">
          ';
      }
      else {
        echo '
            <h1 class="herotext sr-hero">'. single_post_title() .'</h1>
            ';
      }
      ?>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.herotext {
  font-size: 10vh;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #EF7F1A;
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: And where is your CSS?

Comment: I think `single_post_title()` returns HTML element, not just text.

Comment: So what should I do diferently to output single_post_title() but with correct styles.
I've already tried changing the h1 for a div, so it would effect the heding tag created by wp but that did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by assigning the .herotext class to the parent div

```
<div class="intro-text child herotext">
      <!--<h1 class="herotext sr-hero">Kompletní<br>realizace staveb.</h1>-->
      <?php
      if ( is_front_page() ) {
          echo '
              <img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/samsonsvg2_animated.svg" class="samsonlogo">
          ';
      }
      else {
        echo '
            <h1 class="sr-hero">'. single_post_title() .'</h1>
            ';
      }
      ?>
    </div>
```